# How to align items or align self with big text using CSS GRID

Tags: css, alignment, css-grid

I have tried for several hours without success...

My goal is to be able to align a large text (main title) by sticking it to the bottom line of my grid cell.

I tried baseline, and flex end with align items on the container and align self on the child without success. Also, some related things seen online about line height and vertical-align...whitout success

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV7vV.png)

```css
.banner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 120vh;
    
}

.title{
    font-size: 6.3rem;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(31, 89, 148);
    font-weight: bold;
    grid-area: 4/3/5/5;
    align-self: baseline;

   
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
    <!--///////////////////////////////// début header//////////////////////////// -->
    <header class="banner">
        <h1 class="title">front pri</h1>
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the `line-height` and vertical margins of the `h1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends, it works! Although I'm a little disappointed that the grid properties alone aren't enough. But it's not a big deal to do when you know it. Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have default margin on your `h1`. Adding `margin-bottom: 0;` to your h1 should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks ! playing with margin-bottom 0; and line height working for me ! SOLVED.